# Picker in a ScrollView doesn't scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipickerview

I have a UIScrollView, inside it, a small UIView containing a UIPickerView.
I'm able to scroll the view up and down but whenever I try to scroll the picker, it scrolls the view instead. I can change the picker's value by clicking it but not scrolling.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I just tried `scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;` but it only works when I first Touch and then Drag, as in the TouchesBegan event. The scrollView still scrolls if I touch-move the Picker as in the TouchesMoved event.

What can I do to give my Picker its natural behavior in a ScrollView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've already got [`canCancelContentTouches`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/canCancelContentTouches) set to `NO`, but try setting [`delaysContentTouches`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/delaysContentTouches) to `NO` as well.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! I have to remove my UIView (which contains the Picker) form the ScrollView and leave only the Picker, though. But I can live with that. Thanks mate!

Comment: Any solution to this for Swift 3?